# Mac Mail: How to have mail popups show for only a couple seconds

Tags: email, notifications

Whenever I get mails from Mail on my mac, they just stays there until I have to manually close the notification. Is there anyway to make the popups automatically go away after 1-2 seconds?

Photo:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned you can change the Notifications settings in Notification Center.

You have the Mail alert style set to **alert** which makes the notification stay until dismissed.

To make the notification disappear after a few seconds you need to change the style to **banners** in Notification Center.

Shown below:

[image: notification]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yea I saw both of those and also the message below the options but it's pretty dumb one has to choose between the two. A simple option where it vanishes and one can dismiss it would make things much easier. The banner does not vanish quick enough.

Comment: @mikanim That’s the only option

Answer (score 0):

You can change notification settings on a Mac through the notification center itself by selecting it then selecting the gear wheel at the very bottom.  You can also change them via System Preferences under Notifications.  Once you're there select the app and change the settings for it.  Different apps may have slightly different settings for notifications and how you can customize them.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204079